# Event loop exception after program finishes

Tags: python, python-asyncio

W.r.t. Łukasz' tutorial on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/-CzqsgaXUM8?t=2279) for a simple web-crawler, the following code gives `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`. This happens after the code runs successfully and prints out the time taken to complete the program.

```
import asyncio
import time
from typing import Callable, Coroutine
import httpx

addr = 'https://langa.pl/crawl'


async def progress(
    url: str,
    algo: Callable[..., Coroutine],
) -> None:

    # store create_task into a variable
    task = asyncio.create_task(
        algo(url),
        name=url,
    )

    todo.add(task)  # add task to todo
    start = time.time()

    while len(todo):

        done, _pending = await asyncio.wait(todo, timeout=0.5)

        # cleanup todo by removing the done task
        todo.difference_update(done)

        # report completed urls
        urls = (t.get_name() for t in todo)

        # prints the current status
        print(f"{len(todo)}: " + " ".join(sorted(urls))[-75:])

    end = time.time()
    print(f"Took {int(end-start)} seconds")


async def crawl3(
    prefix: str, url: str = "",
) -> None:
    url = url or prefix
    client = httpx.AsyncClient()
    try:
        res = await client.get(url)
    finally:
        await client.aclose()

    for line in res.text.splitlines():
        if line.startswith(prefix):
            task = asyncio.create_task(
                crawl3(prefix, line),
                name=line,
            )

            todo.add(task)

todo = set()
asyncio.run(progress(addr, crawl3))
```

Why is this happening? What needs to be changed in the code?

Comment: What OS are you running the code on?

Comment: Windows 10 operating system

Comment: Looks like [this issue](https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/914).

Comment: @user4815162342: Yes! That was the issue. Fixed it by adding `if sys.version_info[0] == 3 and sys.version_info[1] >= 8 and sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())` after the imports.

**Note**: `time.sleep(0.1)` as the last line of *progress* did not work for me in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved from pointer given by @user4815162342 - being tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/encode/httpx/issues/914)

```
import asyncio

import sys ## added to prevent Event Loop exception

import time
from typing import Callable, Coroutine

import httpx

## added to prevent Event Loop exception...
if sys.version_info[0] == 3 and sys.version_info[1] >= 8 and sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

addr = 'https://langa.pl/crawl'
...
```